# Is there any way to find classes with bad package name in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors, package

After years of Java develoment, I was shocked to learn that the compiler doesn't check if the package name really is the one corresponding to the Java source file's path.

You *can* write this:

```
package abcd; 
class Xyz {
}
```

and it *will* compile even is Xyz.java is located in efgh folder. I get a warning while editing the file in Netbeans, but that's about it. In fact, this had led to a bug that was very difficult to spot: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=197320

Any way to get warnings or errors anyway?

Comment: Use Eclipse. It will give error if package is wrong.

Comment: I suppose javac allows this because you have the -d option which could theoretically clean this up.

Comment: javac -d won't solve that. I don't want javac to solve that, I just want it to report it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With gnu-find, you can search a whole project. cd to the project source root, and then:

```
find PROJECT -type f -name "*.java" -exec ./pmatchd.sh {} ";"
```

You need the pmatchd.sh - script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
dir=$(dirname $1)
d=${dir//\//.}
headline=$(head -n1 $1) 
p=${headline#package }
if [[ $d";" != $p ]]
then 
    echo "mismatch: " + $d " " + $p + " " + $1
fi
```

If you like it, you will move it to a location in the path, not in the $PWD.

Comment: good idea, and I can make this part of our continuous integration process... I'll check that and come back asap :-)

Comment: however, I'd rather use something that's part of the java ecosystem if possible

Comment: I understand that, but it's too much work for me. However there are some improvements possible: The scripts should work without `cd`ing to the directory. And maybe the 'package' statement isn't always in the first line. I guess in scala you could do it in 30 lines, in Java 100 lines. :)

Comment: actually, I was looking for some compiler switch or some tool that's part of the distribution. Seems it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an error; it's an inconvenience. You could put every .java file in a single directory, with each class in a different package, and still compile properly and get an output structure that matched what the classes' packages were.

Comment: Your statement is correct, but I'd like to know how to report the inconvenience, if possible at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

A package name is nothing but a namespace. It can be converted to a file path and most classloaders expect to find the compiled class file at location like

```
<classpath-entry>/packagename.replace(".","/")/classname.class
```

(But that's classloader business)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will not allow this and will show it as a compile error.  If Netbeans just shows this as a warning, you might be able to change it to show as an error in the compile settings.

Comment: Netbeans uses javac, so the question applies to it.